# Emphasize on line of the grid with Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

I am using Seaborn to plot a violin graph (as you can see on the pic below):
[image: Violin Plot]

I would like to emphasize the line at the 0 level on the y-axis (Comparison_perc) and then make it slightly bigger/darker.

Would you know how?

Many thanks,

Guillaume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can add a horizontal line using [axhline()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html) e.g.

```
#Import libraries
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Load example dataset
dataset = sns.load_dataset("iris")

#Create graph
graph = sns.barplot(x="sepal_width", y="petal_width", data=dataset)

#Draw a horizontal line at 0
graph.axhline(y=0)

#Show plot
plt.show()
```

And you can change the color/thickness etc, e.g. `graph.axhline(y=0, linewidth=4, color='r')`

Comment: It does the trick, thanks Jared!

Comment: You're welcome - thanks for making a clear/concise question with all the required details :)